# Restore iOS default settings without user interaction

Tags: iphone, restore, automation

I have some iOS devices in a device farm that I'm trying to automate as much as possible. I'd like to be able to clean them after use (i.e. restore them to a set state) without having to physically interact with the devices.

So far, I've found I can do this:

1. Install `idevicebackup2` from [libimobiledevice](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice)
2. Run `idevicebackup2 backup /tmp/iphonebackup`
3. Run `idevicebackup2 restore /tmp/iphonebackup --system --reboot`
4. Wait for reboot

After the reboot, "Update Complete", then "Welcome to iPhone" screens are present. These interfere with automated operation of the device (e.g. launching apps). I hoped I could launch an XCUITest to navigate through this pointless wizard but I get `Could not launch “WebDriverAgent”: Unlock the device “iPhone” and repeat the action` in Xcode when attempting this.

Is it possible to skip this setup wizard after restoring settings? Or is there another way to reset the phone to a state where I can interact with it from the command line successfully?